# Setting Default Printer in Windows RDP Based on Client Location (Building)

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server, group-policy, windows-administration

I have a Windows Terminal Server hosted in the cloud, and clients connect to it using Windows RDP. We have multiple printers rolled out based on the user, and these users work in different buildings. What I'm trying to achieve is setting the default printer for each user based on their location (building).

Is there a way to obtain the client's location information through the RDP client and define the default printer accordingly, possibly through Group Policy or other means?

Here are some specific details:

- We have multiple printers available, and users can have connections
  to all of them.
- Users may work in different buildings, and we want to
  set the default printer based on their current location.
- The terminal
  server is hosted in the cloud.
- We are open to using Group Policy or
  other configuration methods. Is there a way to achieve this, and if
  so, what steps or configuration options should I consider? Any code
  or script examples would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Context:

- We've looked into Group Policy settings, but it's not clear how to
  dynamically set the default printer based on the client's location.
- We're interested in any possible solutions, including script-based
  ones.